# Set default value in stylus mixin

Tags: mixins, stylus

Using stylus I want to create a mixin that uses the right image based on a `locale` option.

**mixin**

```
    locale-image(name, locale)
      if locale is not defined
         locale = 'en-US'
      background-image url('../images/'locale'/'name'.jpg')
```

**Example Usage:**

```
.us-image
    locale-image('my-us-image')

.ge-image
    locale-image('my-german-image', 'de-DE')
```

Basically is there a way to leave off a parameter like in the US example? How can I modify my mixin to support this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you can use [argument defaults](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/functions.html#argument-defaults):

```
  locale-image(name, locale = 'en-US')
    background-image url('../images/' + locale + '/' + name + '.jpg')

  .us-image
    locale-image('my-us-image')

  .ge-image
    locale-image('my-german-image', 'de-DE')
```